# dnn 6.0 - cannot get rss icon to show on modules

Tags: rss, dotnetnuke

I'm running dnn 06.01.04 (127) community edition and cannot get the rss icon to show on the links module or announcements module. I have allow syndicate checked and show container checked in the settings for each module. If I use the manage menu and manually click syndicate the xml file is created and I am shown the rss feed and am able to subscribe. However, the rss icon will not show on any modules on the site. I am using the DarkKnight - 2-Column-Right-Mega-Menu skin and the DarkKnight - PageTitle_Blue container. How can I get the rss icon to show on the links and announcements modules? Thanks all for any feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is a known bug in dnn 6.x - I am not running the latest dnn 6.x version so perhaps it has been fixed in the most recent 6.x version. From what I have researched though it has not been fixed yet. See [this link](http://www.ifinity.com.au/Products/Support_Forums/forumid/10/postid/7175/scope/posts) and [this one](http://www.ifinity.com.au/Products/Support_Forums/forumid/10/postid/7175/scope/posts). There is a [hack found here](http://www.dnncreative.com/Forum/tabid/88/aft/30528/%5bLink%5d) that will let you get around this bug.

Update - I just upgraded to the latest dnn version 06.02.02 released August 2012 and this has not yet been fixed and still is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have found a bug, or are you using a container that doesn't include the RSS icon option in it? I don't believe that the containers in DNN6 actually provide a place for the icon, you would need to add it yourself.